# Create combo-box with arrow to increment value inside it

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jspinner

I have to create the classic combo-box with arrows up and down to increment value inside box. I want to implement something like this:

[image: box]

What is the Java Swing equivalent of this component?

Comment: Look at using a [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LimitValueSpinner{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Limiting value for a JSpinner");
  SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 100, 1); //default value,lower bound,upper bound,increment by
  JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(spinner);
  frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  frame.setSize(400, 400);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: `setSize()` or `pack()` and `setVisible(...)` must always comes under `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`, never inside the `main` method. +1 for the rest :-)

Comment: and JSpinner in this form allowing input any type of chars [A-Z] & [0-9]